# jQuery replace hangs chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this script freeze up Chrome? Also, is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do (replace all instances of a word with another word)?

```
<html>
  <body>      
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    var replaced = $("body").html().replace('Foo','Bar');
    $("body").html(replaced);
    });
      </script>
      <p>Foo</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the script that does the replacement is in the body. When you call `.html(HTMLString)` and `HTMLString` contains a `<script>`, jQuery executes the script. So after you replace the body, you're calling the code that replaces the body again, and when it runs it calls itself again, and so on.

You're also loading another copy of jQuery every time you do the replacement, because `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">` is in the body.

One solution would be to put all the scripts in the `<head>` instead of the body. Another would be if you targetted just a container DIV that contains the real content of the page.

```
<html>
  <body>      
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        var replaced = $("#content").html().replace(/Foo/g,'Bar');
        $("#content").html(replaced);
    });
      </script>
      <div id="content">
        <p>Foo</p>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, when you give a string as the first argument to `.replace()`, it only replaces the first match. If you want to replace all matches, you need to use a regular expression with the `g` modifier.

Comment: Nice catch! Just wanted to add that he might want to use `$("body").html().replace(/Foo/g,'Bar');` to replace all instances instead of just the first...once he solves your problem.

Comment: You can also make use of callback of `.html`. `$("#content").html(function(i, oldHtml) { return oldHtml.replace(/Foo/g, 'Bar'); });`

Comment: @Tushar I like to use that in place of a `.each()` loop. When there's just one element being selected, I think the straightforward code is clearer.